# Infrastructure instance stuck in deregistering on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

My Infrastrucutre is stuck in Deregistering. I move the cursor to Deregistering... there comes popup `agent disconnected`

[image]

[image]

However no EC2 instance such as `i-03d8b4d9f9144e415` and `i-020cf8519dfcedf35`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' 
[
    "i-08b54f1225eba9b8e",
    "i-06c5cfde9a5b62b2a",
    "i-027631d87b07f12b8",
    "i-031435737ef425f0b"
]
```

There is neither service, nor auto capacity provider

```
aws ecs list-services --cluster=quc-dev-ec2-cluster

{
    "serviceArns": []
}
aws ecs describe-capacity-providers
{
    "capacityProviders": [
        {
            "capacityProviderArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100228111:capacity-provider/FARGATE",
            "name": "FARGATE",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "tags": []
        },
        {
            "capacityProviderArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100228111:capacity-provider/FARGATE_SPOT",
            "name": "FARGATE_SPOT",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "tags": []
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

I try to deregister the instances.

```
aws ecs deregister-container-instance --container-instance=d99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca --cluster=quc-dev-ec2-cluster --force --debug

2023-06-28 15:10:43,887 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64
2023-06-28 15:10:43,887 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecs', 'deregister-container-instance', '--container-instance=d99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca', '--cluster=quc-dev-ec2-cluster', '--force', '--debug']
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_s3 at 0x104f3e660>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_ddb at 0x104a6b420>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method BasicCommand.add_command of <class 'awscli.customizations.configure.configure.ConfigureCommand'>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function change_name at 0x10495e340>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function change_name at 0x1049f18a0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function alias_opsworks_cm at 0x104f4e0c0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_history_commands at 0x104ac25c0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method BasicCommand.add_command of <class 'awscli.customizations.devcommands.CLIDevCommand'>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x104f4d080>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x104ff8650>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,906 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/data/cli.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_types at 0x104b8dee0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function no_sign_request at 0x104b8e200>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_verify_ssl at 0x104b8e160>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_cli_read_timeout at 0x104b8e340>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_cli_connect_timeout at 0x104b8e2a0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <built-in method update of dict object at 0x105001a80>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecs', 'deregister-container-instance', '--container-instance=d99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca', '--cluster=quc-dev-ec2-cluster', '--force', '--debug']
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_timestamp_parser at 0x104f3f100>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,907 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x10468d580>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,908 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_binary_formatter at 0x104fb7380>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,908 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function no_pager_handler at 0x104679d00>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,908 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x1046cf560>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,909 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/
2023-06-28 15:10:43,912 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x104ac1da0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,912 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_json_file_cache at 0x104a5f4c0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,921 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/service-2.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,925 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <function inject_commands at 0x104b6e0c0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,925 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x104f4d080>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,933 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,933 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x104ff8650>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([('cluster', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1051bb150>), ('container-instance', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1051bb290>), ('force', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x1051bb3d0>), ('no-force', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x1051bb450>)])
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x104f3f740>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function rename_arg.<locals>._rename_arg at 0x104fdf240>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x1046e8040>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function add_cli_input_yaml at 0x1046e82c0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,934 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x104a6bba0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/paginators-1.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x104b8c5e0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x1051bb750>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x1051bb7d0>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1051c1c50>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs_deregister-container-instance: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x104f4d080>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs_deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x104ff8650>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.cluster: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1047410d0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'quc-dev-ec2-cluster' for parameter "cluster": 'quc-dev-ec2-cluster'
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.container-instance: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1047410d0>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'd99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca' for parameter "container_instance": 'd99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca'
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.force: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.cli-input-json: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.cli-input-yaml: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.deregister-container-instance.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x105034750>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x1051bb750>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x1051bb7d0>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.deregister-container-instance: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1051c1c50>>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2023-06-28 15:10:43,942 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2023-06-28 15:10:43,943 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2023-06-28 15:10:43,943 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,948 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x103926e80>
2023-06-28 15:10:43,957 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/endpoint-rule-set-1.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,957 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/partitions.json
2023-06-28 15:10:43,957 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.ecs: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x10386a020>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting ecs timeout as (60, 60)
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Calling endpoint provider with parameters: {'Region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'UseDualStack': False, 'UseFIPS': False}
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Endpoint provider result: https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event provide-client-params.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <function base64_decode_input_blobs at 0x104fb7420>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x103945260>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x103946d40>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,030 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=DeregisterContainerInstance) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.DeregisterContainerInstance', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/ecs.deregister-container-instance'}, 'body': b'{"cluster": "quc-dev-ec2-cluster", "containerInstance": "d99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca", "force": true}', 'url': 'https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x1055c8a50>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x1023f8790>>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x103945120>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20230628T061044Z
x-amz-target:AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.DeregisterContainerInstance

content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
f470706f5c84b433bdf0dc0e22fb3aa4cf3f8f981ea625432c0ffb49d8f8176f
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230628T061044Z
20230628/ap-northeast-1/ecs/aws4_request
5f376aa7a7ad8539c2cb799ed2b29afdb667b90fa08c8e3d21068ebe50a990f1
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
2032237aad0dad39655fff0b892fb97beac28f07e6cda393dba4231a6129921e
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'X-Amz-Target': b'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.DeregisterContainerInstance', 'Content-Type': b'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/ecs.deregister-container-instance', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230628T061044Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAZ3YPMLASV6736UA4/20230628/ap-northeast-1/ecs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=2032237aad0dad39655fff0b892fb97beac28f07e6cda393dba4231a6129921e', 'Content-Length': '106'}>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - botocore.httpsession - DEBUG - Certificate path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/cacert.pem
2023-06-28 15:10:44,031 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443
2023-06-28 15:10:44,751 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 5064
2023-06-28 15:10:44,752 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-RequestId': '6eee40d3-efc9-46c6-b55b-902387a88e1c', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'Content-Length': '5064', 'Date': 'Wed, 28 Jun 2023 06:10:43 GMT'}
2023-06-28 15:10:44,753 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'{"containerInstance":{"agentConnected":false,"agentUpdateStatus":"PENDING","attachments":[],"attributes":[{"name":"ecs.capability.secrets.asm.environment-variables"},{"name":"ecs.capability.branch-cni-plugin-version","value":"a21d3a41-"},{"name":"ecs.ami-id","value":"ami-0358ca9c980a49a61"},{"name":"ecs.capability.secrets.asm.bootstrap.log-driver"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eia.optimized-cpu"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.none"},{"name":"ecs.capability.ecr-endpoint"},{"name":"ecs.capability.docker-plugin.local"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-cpu-mem-limit"},{"name":"ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.bootstrap.log-driver"},{"name":"ecs.capability.efsAuth"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.30"},{"name":"ecs.capability.full-sync"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.31"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.32"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.fluentd"},{"name":"ecs.capability.firelens.options.config.file"},{"name":"ecs.availability-zone","value":"ap-northeast-1c"},{"name":"ecs.capability.aws-appmesh"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.24"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eni-trunking"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.26"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.27"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.privileged-container"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"},{"name":"ecs.cpu-architecture","value":"x86_64"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"},{"name":"ecs.capability.firelens.fluentbit"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.20"},{"name":"ecs.os-type","value":"linux"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eni-block-instance-metadata"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.22"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.23"},{"name":"ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eia"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.syslog"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awsfirelens"},{"name":"ecs.capability.firelens.options.config.s3"},{"name":"ecs.awsvpc-trunk-id","value":"5bf46150-3e73-4583-b496-b7e775ad766e"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.json-file"},{"name":"ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"},{"name":"ecs.vpc-id","value":"vpc-7b01071c"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"},{"name":"ecs.capability.docker-plugin.amazon-ecs-volume-plugin"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eni"},{"name":"ecs.capability.firelens.fluentd"},{"name":"ecs.capability.efs"},{"name":"ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"},{"name":"ecs.capability.task-eni.ipv6"},{"name":"ecs.capability.container-health-check"},{"name":"ecs.capability.execute-command"},{"name":"ecs.subnet-id","value":"subnet-0c5e41d2f232f12fc"},{"name":"ecs.instance-type","value":"c5.large"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role-network-host"},{"name":"ecs.capability.container-ordering"},{"name":"ecs.capability.cni-plugin-version","value":"55b2ae77-2020.09.0"},{"name":"ecs.capability.env-files.s3"},{"name":"ecs.capability.pid-ipc-namespace-sharing"},{"name":"ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.environment-variables"},{"name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"}],"capacityProviderName":"quc-dev-admin-cp","containerInstanceArn":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100228133:container-instance/quc-dev-ec2-cluster/d99fc29efee34409b17f30c34fe775ca","ec2InstanceId":"i-03d8b4d9f9144e415","pendingTasksCount":0,"registeredAt":1.687719583587E9,"registeredResources":[{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":2048,"longValue":0,"name":"CPU","type":"INTEGER"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":3722,"longValue":0,"name":"MEMORY","type":"INTEGER"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":0,"longValue":0,"name":"PORTS","stringSetValue":["22","2376","2375","51678","51679"],"type":"STRINGSET"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":0,"longValue":0,"name":"PORTS_UDP","stringSetValue":[],"type":"STRINGSET"}],"remainingResources":[{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":2048,"longValue":0,"name":"CPU","type":"INTEGER"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":3722,"longValue":0,"name":"MEMORY","type":"INTEGER"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":0,"longValue":0,"name":"PORTS","stringSetValue":["22","2376","2375","51678","51679"],"type":"STRINGSET"},{"doubleValue":0.0,"integerValue":0,"longValue":0,"name":"PORTS_UDP","stringSetValue":[],"type":"STRINGSET"}],"runningTasksCount":0,"status":"DEREGISTERING","tags":[],"version":10,"versionInfo":{"agentHash":"5c821610","agentVersion":"1.51.0","dockerVersion":"DockerVersion: 20.10.13"}}}'
2023-06-28 15:10:44,755 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x105618290>>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,755 - MainThread - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2023-06-28 15:10:44,755 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.ecs.DeregisterContainerInstance: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x102dc8210>>
2023-06-28 15:10:44,756 - MainThread - awscli.formatter - DEBUG - RequestId: 6eee40d3-efc9-46c6-b55b-902387a88e1c
```

But in vain. It remains as `Deregistering`. and consequently I can not delete the cluster.

```
aws ecs delete-cluster --cluster=quc-dev-ec2-cluster       

An error occurred (ClusterContainsContainerInstancesException) when calling the DeleteCluster operation: The Cluster cannot be deleted while Container Instances are active or draining.
```

Does anyone have the same situation?

Comment: Can you check if the subnet which you are deploying is private subnet and has nat gaeway to communicate with the ECS service.  If the ec2 is in public subnet and doesnt have public IP due to subnet default it wont be able to communicate with ECS. Check if there is any Autoscaling group which you can scale down to 0 and then try deleting the cluster

Comment: @Vikram S Thank you very much for your comment, ec2 is not existed in instances, it is only remained in ECS infrastracture pane. But, they were private subnet with nat when they existed. And there is no Auto scaling group remained. Infrastrucure instance remains like a ghost. So I guess it might be a bug.

Comment: In short, container instance is remained but instance itself is disappeared.